# Question regarding notation $f(\cdot,z)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. If a function $f:X\times G\to \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $\forall z\in G$: $f(\cdot,z)$ is measurable on X, does that mean $x\mapsto f(x,z)$ is measurable for each fixed $z$?.

I'm not certain about the notation $f(\cdot ,z)$

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. $f(\cdot,z)$ stands for the function prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x,z)$.

Comment: The dot can be interpreted as "insert argument(s) here".